# How to solve RDS MySQL (timed out) connection issue

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I deployed my Flask application using Zappa. I use SQLAlchemy and in the environment variables in the `zappa_settings.json` file, I set the database URL that included the endpoint.

Here is the error I find when I see the logs with `zappa tail`:

```
(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '<the-endpoint> (timed out)")
```

where `<the-endpoint>` is the end point at my RDS DB instance for MySQL.

Comment: Can you connect using the mysql client from your app host to the RDS instance? My first thought is that the security group either on the app host or on the RDS instance is not allowing connections. Or there's no route between the subnets or something. This is likely to be an AWS infrastructure issue, not a code issue.

Comment: Yes, I can. I can connect to it through sqlelectron

Comment: Does that mean you are using the sqlelectron terminal UI, and that client is running on the host to which you deploy your Flask application? Testing sqlelectron or another client running on your workstation does not test the same route, and it might work while your Flask app on an app host does not.

Comment: I tested it on the same endpoint. I've just tested it now on the Flask app host with `flask run` and it's giving me the same error without the timed out error: `"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbserver'` although `dbserver` is not the db name nor the endpoint that I set as the environment variable

Comment: I mean run a MySQL client on the Flask app host.

Comment: Not really sure how I can do that

Comment: ssh to the Flask app host (which I assume is an EC2 instance), and run `mysql`. Or you may use `nc` or `telnet` or any other client with which you can open a TCP/IP connection to an endpoint and port you specify.

Comment: The thing is I run Flask locally and I ship to AWS with Zappa which is a serverless tool that bundles that Flask app into a zip file and uploads it to AWS Lambda.
I think you mean to run MySQL client on that localhost if I understand correctly

Comment: If so, it's running on the localhost and has all the expected tables

Comment: Okay, I was not familiar with Zappa, so thanks for clarifying that it is some Lambda deployment thing. I understand why you cannot ssh to a Lambda. But the problem remains that apparently your Lambda environment does not have a route to your RDS instance. This goes back to what I mentioned earlier, it's probably some AWS configuration problem, not a code problem.

Comment: Have you read instructions like this one: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-lambda-to-an-rds-instance/

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why it's not working locally. I receive almost the same error without deploying the app: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbserver' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")`

Comment: So you can't reach your RDS instance from either a local client or your deployed lambda client? Could your Flask app be using the wrong endpoint name?